# Remove password feature from USB

Tags: usb, password-protection

I've been stuck with this question for a while and never found a solution.
My USB has a password protection feature on it and I think it stops it from being bootable.

Locked:

[image: usb locked]

Unlocked:

[image: usb unlocked]

Does anyone know a way to remove this feature and make it bootable?
Perhaps reflashing the usb stick?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

It seems to follow this standard: IEEE1667

I found this chinese(?) page with some low level tools which I can try:
http://dl.mydigit.net/special/up/phison.html

Comment: Can you give any details on the pendrive's model or at least manufacturer?

Comment: @gronostaj I believe the brand name is silicon power.

Comment: @gronostaj The model is D33B29 I think it's also known as Helios 101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note** Try using the UFD Recover Tool I mention at the end of my post FIRST, maybe just that is enough, I didn't find it until my last couple of steps.

I ended up using [ChipGenius](http://mympx.org/Downloads/p13_sectionid/2/p13_fileid/85) to find my VID and PID.
I filled those two in on [flashboot.ru](http://flashboot.ru/iflash/) and found out which controller I was dealing with. It was a Phison, then I googled and downloaded Phison MPALL v3.29.0B and with a combination of using this [guide](http://jeffgraves.me/2012/03/09/running-windows-8-server-from-a-usb-flash-drive-with-phison-controller/) and a lot of trouble shooting I finally got it to disable IEEE 1667 (mode 3).

In the end I ended up having a "Super Floppy". Then I finished off using this [UFD Recover Tool](http://www.silicon-power.com/UFD_Recover_Tool/UFD_Recover_Tool.rar). And now I have a USB with MBR, without IEEE 1667 (password) and perfectly bootable.

Answer (score 2):

I think if you format your USB drive it will lose all settings including password ones.

Comment: It didn't make a difference, tried everything with the partitions using EaseUS Partition Manager but the whole password feature isn't on the partitions. It doesn't show up as a disk if I don't unlock it by entering my password first.

Comment: But you formatted only a partition or the entire disk?

Comment: I formatted the entire disk, pretty much tried every option that mentioned "wipe" or "rebuild" or "delete" on the disk and on the partition. Didn't seem to make any difference.